# What is an optimal way to control requests to the same API, having a request limit, across all DAGs in Airflow

Tags: python, python-requests, airflow

In our Airflow we have multiple DAGs using the same API, which limits requests to 1 request per 10 ms. What is an optimal way to control requests to the same API across all DAGs?

Answer (score 1):

[Pools](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/pools.html#pools) are used to limit concurrency for a resource across multiple DAGs.

For example, if you define a pool `my_pool` with 1 slot.

```
airflow pools set my_pool 1
```

And you have a DAG with 2 tasks as:

```
with DAG(
    'tutorial',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="@once",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 6, 1),
) as dag:

    t1 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='t1_task',
        pool='my_pool'
    )

    t2 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='t2_task',
        pool='my_pool'
    )
```

In this DAG `t1_task` & `t2_task` can not run in parallel because they are both subject to `my_pool` which has only 1 slot. `t1_task` may run before `t2_task` or `t2_task` may run before `t1_task`

Answer (score 1):

It's not straightforward. There is no direct way to limit API calls across multiple DAGS/Tasks because they are run in independent processes/nodes.

The best you can do is to introduce a proxy that all requests are going through and introduce rate limiting there (example rate-limiting proxy you can find here: [Sphinx](https://github.com/Clever/sphinx). This is the common best practice in many "serious" deployments that this kind of rate limiting is provided by some kind of proxies or "Gateways".

If you are in a cloud environment you can actually use existing API gateways for that purpose: [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway), [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/).

Approaching it throug proxy/Gateway has the added benefit that you can rate-limit requests not only from single Airflow Installation, but also from all the other sources of API calls for the service (which will inevitably happen eventually)

So, there is not much Airflow can (and should) do about it if you actually want to protect against rate limit for the "best" scenario where you want to protect against exceeding the limits in general.

However, you can make your Airflow installation somewhat more resilient to those kind of errors, and/or configure it in the way that the rate limits are happening less frequently (at least in the case where those calls are mostly generated by Airflow)

1. you can limit the number of parallell request to the API by using the [Pools](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/pools.html) that Elad mentioned in the previous answer. There you can limit a number of concurrent tasks running in a pool. All tasks that cause the API call should belong to the same "pool" and you can limit how many of those tasks can run in parallel. This is quite nice because it is managed on the "Scheduler" level - which means that if the pools are "full", Airflow will not schedule any more of those "pool" tasks and the workers you have configured for airflow remain free for other tasks (Or Kubernetes Pods are not created) until the pool is "full". This way you make sure Airflow on its own does not flood the API with too many requests in too short time (max number of requests = `<pool size>/<average length of the task>` assuming all tasks are similar and generate one API call per task execution). This way airflow might be "nice citizen" for others using same API. But it does not protect you from "others" using the same API.
2. In order to make Airflow more resilient to such retries, you should use/implement retries with exponential back-off for Hooks that make the API calls that you want to rate-limit. Some of the "rate-limit-vulnerable" hooks which are implemented in Airflow Community providers already use that approach. For example you can see how Dataprep is doing it:
   https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/763919d4152ffa13433e2489fec85ed286b7b196/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataprep.py#L61

It's super-easy to implement such retries. As you can see in the example above, this is a simple tenacity retry decorator with some parameters that make it retry several times with exponential back-off and custom method to decide whether the error is "permanent" or "retriable". This approach provides resilience in many situations. For example when you exceed rate yourself, when there is a sudden spike of requests, when others are causing the rate limit to be exceeded etc., etc. Ideally if all users of the rate-limiting API implement it, then the system becomes "self-healing" in all situations. This has the drawback however, that while such request waits, the worker/POD of airflow continues to run, actively sleeping, thus blocking an execution slot for other tasks.

In the future when Airflow implements [Deferrable "Async" Operators](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=177050929) (this is work in progress and will be there in Airflow 2.2 or 2.3), we will be able to get the best of both approaches. We will be able to make the operators retry with exponential back-off, while also freeing the running workers to perform other tasks.