How to write a proper Airflow semaphores between dags
I have about 15 workflows that need to run on different schedules or with different triggers. But the orchestration that I need means that some workflows aren't allowed to run when some others are running and need to be differed. I am trying to write a pretty and easy solution. One of the key requirements is that a workflow can have multiple locks.
e.g. Task A can run if Task B runs, but task C cannot run if task A or B runs.
This could be done by adding a lock "TaskALock" to task A,
A "TaskBlock" to task B
and "TaskAlock" & "TaskBLock" to Task C
This is what I currently have as an example DAG:
@dag(
    catchup=False,
    tags=["staging"],
    start_date=datetime(2021, 12, 21),
    schedule="*/5 2-17 * * 1-5",
)
def validate_transactions():
    locks = [TRANSACTION_VALIDATION]
    transaction_validation = TransactionValidation()

    @task()
    def get_transactions_to_validate():
        return transaction_validation.get_to_validate_transactions()

    @task()
    def validate_transaction(transaction_id: int):
        return transaction_validation.validate_transactions(transaction_id)

    @teardown()
    def unlock():
        free_locks(locks)

    t1 = get_lock(locks)
    t2 = get_transactions_to_validate()
    t3 = validate_transaction.expand(transaction_id=t2)
    t4 = unlock()
    t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4


validate_transactions()

Where get_lock and unlock are defined in:
def create_redis_object():
    host = os.environ.get("BROKER_URL")
    port = int(os.environ.get("BROKER_PORT"))
    return redis.Redis(host=host, port=port, db=9)


cache = create_redis_object()


@task.sensor(poke_interval=60, timeout=3600, mode="reschedule")
def get_lock(locks: List[str] | str):
    run_id = get_current_context()['dag_run'].run_id
    if isinstance(locks, str):
        locks = [locks]
    allowed = True
    for lock_name in locks:
        logging.info(f"Trying to get lock: {lock_name}")
        if allowed and cache.get(lock_name) is not None:
            allowed = False
    if allowed:
        for lock_name in locks:
            cache.setnx(lock_name, run_id)
    if PokeReturnValue is not None:
        return PokeReturnValue(allowed)
    else:
        return allowed


def free_locks(locks):
    for lock_name in locks:
        try:
            cache.delete(lock_name)
            logging.info(f"Freed lock {lock_name}")
        except:
            logging.warning(f"Could not free lock {lock_name}")

But I was thinking of writing an own custom @dag decorator that would automatically add the get_lock and free_locks tasks, rather than having to redo it every single dag again and again.
But I am a bit stuck on how I would do such a thing and am looking for suggestions.

See Airflow Pools https://stackoverflow.com/a/68518695/14624409

Thank you for the reply. I checked out the pools, but one of the requirements is to have "multiple locks", is there a way to have this? I added the requirement and a description to the ticket.

Not yet https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13975
